# What is BearerOption.SaveToken property used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

What bearerOption.SaveToken property used for in the configuration of JwtAuthentication in aspnet core 2 ?

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(bearer =>
                    {
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = signingKey as SecurityKey;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = true;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.RequireExpirationTime = true;
                        bearer.TokenValidationParameters.RequireSignedTokens = true;
                        // ******
                        bearer.SaveToken = true;
                        // ******
                    });
```

Comment: Similar: [What is the purpose of JwtBearerOptions.SaveToken property in ASP.NET Core 2.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57057749)

Answer (score 5):

It is a property that defines whether the bearer token should be stored in the [AuthenticationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.0) after a successful authorization.

Comment: I have seen that in the documentation but i don't understand why ?

Comment: the bearer token is stored through out the lifetime of the users session to validate it is them.

Comment: Where is the token saved if `SaveTokens = false` then? How does the MVC client obtain the `access_token`?

Comment: @Dai The token has already been validated and claims copied into User; the JSON itself is no longer needed unless SaveTokens=true. See https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/#when-validation-is-successful

Comment: @Benrobot That article is from 2016, ASP.NET Core's security code has been completely overhauled since then (_twice_, I think...). Secondarily, you still need the entire, unmodified `access_token` for accessing secondary RPs.

Comment: @Dai, it is my understanding that access to secondary resources that require the same JWT needs SaveToken=true. If SaveToken=false then the `access_token` would not be available. I agree it is an old article, I couldn't find anything newer.

Answer (score 2):

You have two option:

1. Save the token as claim.
   Then you can get '**access_token**' by below code:

   `string accessToken = User.FindFirst("access_token")?.Value;`
2. Save the token in the AuthenticationProperties.
   Then you have to set '**SaveToken**' option to **true** and get access token by below code:

   `string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");`

Comment: I've set SaveToken as true, but still token return as null above code