# What is the purpose of JwtBearerOptions.SaveToken property in ASP.NET Core 2.0+?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.savetoken?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerOptions_SaveToken) just have this description:

> Defines whether the bearer token should be stored in the [AuthenticationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.2) after a successful authorization.

I wondered if saving the JWT allows you to revoke it somehow, but every place I read about JWTs says they are irrevocable. What would you do with a JWT being stored in the AuthenticationProperties?

Comment: Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302473/what-is-beareroption-savetoken-property-used-for?noredirect=1#comment116408234_49302473

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Storing the JWT in the `AuthenticationProperties` allows you to retrieve it from elsewhere within your application.

For example, use [`GetTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationtokenextensions.gettokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) inside of an action, like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    // ...
}
```

This is useful if, for example, you want to forward the JWT in an outgoing request.

Comment: Is the name 'access_token' by some sort of convention? Or it can be customized?

Comment: @Nico Yes and no. The name `access_token` originates in OAuth2 (and OIDC) though the use of it with `GetTokenAsync` is hardcoded in ASP.NET Core's token handling. I think the situation is a bit of a mess. I believe you can customize it if you know what you're doing (subclassing is required, IIRC) but not worth the effort.