# Accessing Payload of JWT with mvc dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, controller

I have a problem with accessing the (payload of) JWT in a dotnet core controller. I don't know where I am wrong. I think I covered all the important points in the following description. If I have missed something, that could help, please let me know.
Thank you for your time.

Adding authentication service to the servicecollection

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidIssuer = null,
                    ValidAudience = null,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testify"))
                };
            });
```

The token I used for the request:

[image: Used Token]

The postman call:
[image: Postman Call]

The code of the controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 201)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 401)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 403)]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "AuditLog")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public IActionResult Insert([Required] Dto.Log auditLog) => RunSafely(() =>
            {
                var log = _mapper.Map<Dto.Log, Log>(auditLog);
                log.CorrelationId = _headerReader.GetCorrelationId(Request?.Headers);

                _logRepository.AddLog(log);
                return this.StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Created);
            });
```

The state of the controller:
[image: Result this = Controller]

Comment: Can someone tell me the problem with my question? Why is nobody responding?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what the issue is. Can you post the code of how you tried to access the jwt, and what errors, if any, did you get?

Comment: The use-case is that the application gets a token that is already validated. So the only thing I need is to get the information of the payload. I thought the first code snippet would provide a functionality to access the tokens payload over the user in the controller.

Comment: I think you need to add .SaveToken = true, like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057749/what-is-the-purpose-of-jwtbeareroptions-savetoken-property-in-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: options.SaveToken = true;

Answer (score 1):

You can access payload of jwt by using `User` object inside of `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` namespace. For example:

```
var claims = User.Claims;
```

The claims object contains payload of jwt. Also, you can access other information like:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{ ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear to me, too, and I am not sure about the creation process of your token. However, I have the exact scenario in one of my projects, which works fine. Here is the code for different puzzles:

Creating the Token:

```
if (user != null)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
    // Create the Token
    var claims = new[]
    {
                      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)
                    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));

    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
      _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
      _config["Tokens:Audience"],
      claims,
      expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
      signingCredentials: creds);

    var results = new
    {
        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
        expiration = token.ValidTo
    };

    return Created("", results);
    }
}
```

For IServiceCollection :

```
      services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
      {
        ValidIssuer = _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = _config["Tokens:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]))
      };
    });
```

And config.json file: (Note that I changed real-world info due to security reasons)

```
  "Tokens": {
"Key": "foo-foo-foo-foo-foo-foo-foo-foo",
"Issuer": "localhost",
"Audience": "localhost"
  }
```

These settings are exact that I'm using in one of my small projects, and It's working fine. Check if something is missing in your project or not.

Comment: As I wrote, I want to access the payload not create a payload. The use-case is that the application gets a token that is already validated. So the only thing I need is to get the information of the payload. I thought the first code snippet would provide a functionality to access the tokens payload over the user in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**RAW PAYLOAD**

You can access the raw JWT access token to get its `JWTPayload` using the following type of code in a .NET API controller:

```cs
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

[Route("api/contacts")]
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
    {
        var authHeader = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();
        var parts = authHeader.Split(' ');
        var accessToken = parts[1];

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
        var payload = token.Payload;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Access token expiry time is {payload.Exp}");

        // Business code goes here
    }
}
```

**CLAIMS**

Microsoft provide a higher level programming model, where by default you never get access to the JWT details. This is a good model to follow - business logic should only ever use a `ClaimsPrincipal`:

```cs
var expiry = this.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "exp");
System.Console.WriteLine($"Access token expiry time is {expiry.Value}");
```

**CUSTOM JWT PROCESSING**

If you want to implement custom behaviour related to JWTs then it is standard to use the extensibility features of the framework. The plumbing then goes into a `middleware` class, so that controller classes stay business focused. A couple of example classes of mine show how to extend the .NET framework:

- [CustomAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/security/CustomAuthenticationHandler.cs)
- [CustomJWTSecurityTokenHandler](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/CustomJwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs)

For more info, see these resources of mine, which are focused on promoting understanding of the important standards based OAuth concepts in APIs:

- [.NET 6 API Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/06/net-core-oauth-coding/)

Answer (score 0):

Within a controller, you can take a dependency on `IHttpContextAccessor` and then, on the `HttpContext`, call the extension method `GetTokenAsync(string)`, which will return the encoded string.

```cs
string encodedToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
JwtSecurityToken decodedToken = new JwtSecurityToken(encodedToken);
string email = decodedToken.Payload["email"].ToString();
```

`JwtSecurityToken` is in the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` namespace, and `GetTokenAsync` extension method of `HttpContext` is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to access payload is by using IHttpContextAccessor injected into your class like below.

```
 public class MyClass: IEwocUser
    {
        private readonly IHeaderDictionary _headers;

        public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _headers = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers;
        }
}
```

From the headers you can filter for Auth token.